# Kestrel needs restarted when TLS certificate renewed

Tags: ssl-certificate, asp.net-core-6.0, kestrel

When our certificate is automatically updated by "Let's Encrypt", it is necessary to restart our web API service to use the new certificate.  I have two challenges:  (1) how to automatically detect when the certificate is renewed, and (2) how to use the new certificate without requiring a restart of the web API service.

We configure Kestrel to support https in the appsettings.json file.  Something similar to:

```
  HttpsInlineCertAndKeyFile": {
    "Url": "https://localhost:5002",
    "Certificate": {
      "Path": "<path to .pem/.crt file>",
      "KeyPath": "<path to .key file>",
      "Password": "$CREDENTIAL_PLACEHOLDER$"
    }
  }
```

We are developing in c# .net core 6

Comment: "certificate is automatically updated by "Let's Encrypt". where it is updating, in your local folder ?

Comment: Yes, the file PEM files are local to Kestrel (always the same place).  Kestrel works fine after the certificate is renewed, but it requires a reboot of the Kestrel service in order to start using the updated certificate.

Comment: Since "Let's Encrypt" uses their own schedule for when to update the certificate, I need to know when the certificate is updated so I can reboot my service, or somehow rebind to the new certificate

Answer (score 3):

There is a possibility to reload the certificate without restarting. basically there is a callback mechanism which loads the certificate for each request.

```
.UseKestrel(options =>
 {
   options.ConfigureHttpsDefaults(o =>
   {
       o.ServerCertificateSelector = (context, dnsName) =>
       {
          return GetCertificateFromPath();
       };
    });
 });
```

since it calls this `GetCertificateFromPath` method for each request so you have to cache the certificate somehow inside the GetCertificateFromPath() method and only read when it is changed.

it should be possible with some way by checking modified date or something.